# How can I match all requests except css/js/img in Express framework?

Tags: node.js, express

Messing around with Node.js and Express. I just have the following right now:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {

});
```

which should catch all urls. What's the best way to exclude static files -- that end in .css, .js and .png (or perhaps begin with "css/", "js/" and "img/") ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put your static files in `./views`. Put them in `./public` and add this line above `app.use(app.router)`:

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

That's all you need, you don't need anything else.

Comment: Yeah, that's actually exactly what I have:
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

But the css still gets caught.

Comment: You have this line above all your routes? and above this line: `app.use(app.router);`

Comment: Ah! That app.use(express.static...) wasn't above app.use(app.router); Many thanks, that did it!

Comment: What `path` means? I have no such variable.

Comment: Also, I got an error `Error: 'app.router' is deprecated!`. Sorry, novice in node. :)

Comment: I've added new info to your answer.

Comment: @Kirby that's a NodeJS lib: const path = require('path');